# Can not access internal web server over IPsec vpn

Tags: vpn, android, ipsec

I have configured my Cisco router(which is my gateway) to handle remote access IPsec VPN connections from Android clients and I have configured my Android phone to connect to the router over the VPN to access my home network.

All client trafic is forced through the tunnel and NAT is disabled for the VPN connection such that the Android phone can not reach the Internet when connected to the VPN.

My internal network is using 10.0.0.0/24 and the VPN clients are assigned addresses from the 192.168.0.0/24 network.

When connected, the Android phone can successfully ping clients on the internal 10.0.0.0/24 network. It can also connect via SSH to them but when trying to access any of the webservers I have running internally it fails.

I can see in the log messages on the webserver that it receives connections from 192.168.0.x/24 addresses but the web pages are never loaded in the web browser on Android, it just hangs waiting.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally identified the problem by running wireshark on the webserver which showed me that larger packets were retransmitted all the time but not small packets.

I solved the problem by adding `ip tcp adjust-mss 1300` to the tunnel interface which causes the router to intervene in the TCP packets when the session is being negotiated and set the max segment size to 1300.